# SQL Server 2008 R2 table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. I need to execute a query that gets the name of a product that has the letter `m` in it and sort these products in descending order by the number of ingredients they have.

`product` table has the name and the product number in it, while table `Madefrom` has ingredient number and product number in it.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where you're having troubles.  This really is a pretty basic SQL statement.

Comment: Show some effort of your own! What do you have? Where are you stuck??

Comment: I gouess you're right marc, and next time i will do that. what I had was 2 different queries, one with all the producuts containing "m" , and one that show the number of ingredients in descending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(MadeFrom.ID)
FROM Product
    INNER JOIN MadeFrom ON MadeFrom.ProductID = Product.ID
WHERE Name LIKE '%m%'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(MadeFrom.ID) DESC
```